# BASH - FOR loop using LS and wildcard

Tags: bash, wildcard

My directory contains the following files:

```
FILE1_h0_something_1950_other.gz
FILE2_h0_something_1950_other.gz
FILE3_h0_something_1950_other.gz
```

Here a portion of my bash script:

```
year=1950
for nc_gz in "$input_path/*h3*$year*.gz"; do
      gunzip $nc_gz
done
```

I noted that SOMETIMES (strange behavior... I except always or never) a file named ***h3*1950*** is created inside my dir.

The code fails when directory contains no gz files.

Where is the issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue without any of the `//processing`? (with the exact program you have there)

Comment: I've just edited the question. I noted that the file "*h0*1950*" is created in another for loop. If no gz files are present, the code goes anyway in the for loop and the gunzip command creates the file.

Comment: what is `$nc`? you don't seem to set it anywhere

Comment: @Alex028502 sorry... $nc_gz. If there are no gz files, it should not go through for loop.... but the gunzip command seems to be executed anyway

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> for nc_gz in "$input_path/*h3*$year*.gz"; do
> ```

You're iterating over a list of one element. Since `"$input_path/*h3*$year*.gz"` is in double quotes, it's a single string. So if the value of `input_path` is `/some/where` and the value of `year` is `2017` then this runs the loop body once, with `nc_gz` set to `/some/where/*h3*2017*.gz`.

> ```
>   gunzip $nc_gz
> ```

Here `$nc_gz` is unquoted, so this applies the [split+glob operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells/171347#171347) to the result. In the example above, `/some/where/*h3*2017*.gz` is expanded to the list of matching files; except if there are no matching files, then this invokes `gunzip` with the argument `/some/where/*h3*2017*.gz`.

First, quote things properly:

- [Use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).
- Don't use double quotes around wildcards.

```
for nc_gz in "$input_path/"*h3*"$year"*.gz; do
      gunzip "$nc_gz"
done
```

This still runs the loop once if the wildcard does not match any files, because of a shell misfeature that non-matching wildcard patterns are left unchanged instead of being expanded to an empty list. In bash (but not in plain sh), you can avoid this by setting the `nullglob` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for nc_gz in "$input_path/"*h3*"$year"*.gz; do
  gunzip "$nc_gz"
done
```

In plain sh, you can avoid this by skipping non-existent files.

```
for nc_gz in "$input_path/"*h3*"$year"*.gz; do
  if [ ! -e "$nc_gz" ]; then continue; fi
  gunzip "$nc_gz"
done
```

Note that I assumed that this was simplified code and you do need the loop to do other things beyond calling `gunzip`. If all you need to do is unzip the files, then you can call `gunzip` a single time, since it supports multiple file arguments.

```
gunzip "$input_path/"*h3*"$year"*.gz
```

This works in the sense of unzipping the files, and it does nothing if the wildcard pattern does not match any file, however gunzip will complain about the non-existent file. Here bash's `nullglob` option won't help you since calling `gunzip` with no file name also doesn't work (it expects to uncompress data from its standard input). You need to test for the number of matching files.

```
unzip_matching_files () {
  if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ]; then return; fi
  gunzip "$@"
}
unzip_matching_files "$input_path/"*h3*"$year"*.gz
```

Comment: The error still occurs. Have you run your code with no gz files inside the input dir?

Comment: @Fab Oh, yes, sorry, I forgot about this case. I've updated my answer to handle it properly. [Don't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Note that the code you posted will _not_ create a file with asterisks in the name under any circumstance; if this happens it's because of something else in the loop.

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob`, I think, rather than `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
for i in $(find ../path1 path2 path3 -name "*.env" 2>/dev/null); do
    echo $i
done
```

Ignore errors with 2>/dev/null, otherwise i.e. path1 does not exist will print

```
find: ‘../path1’: No such file or directory
```